# Using version control systems with Qlik Sense Enterprise

Tags: git, qliksense

We are using Qlik Sense Enterprise and have implemented Git source control and Azure pipelines for the mashup and the data load scripts.
We are looking for an option to apply source control to the Qlik App, which is stored in the .QVF file. We have explored exporting/serializing the objects into JSON files, but we have issues with sorting in a consistent way to be able to compare changes. Most of the solutions are several years old.
Could anyone recommend more recent open-source solution for the Qlik App source control?

Answer (score 1):

You could try free easy-to-use tool Gitoqlok - https://gitoqlok.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these solutions:

- [qlik-cli](https://qlik.dev/libraries-and-tools/qlik-cli/app-unbuild) - this CLI tool is managed and supporte by Qlik themselves. The tool have `unbuild` (and `build`) command that can export the content of an app (including the script i think) to json/yaml files
- [gitoqlik](https://gitoqlik.com/) - (havent used it myself) Chrome extension that can directly commit to GitHub (or Gitlab or Bitbucket)
- [enigma mixin](https://github.com/countnazgul/enigma-mixin#buildunbuild) - ive published Enigma mixin NPM package that have similar `build`/`unbuild` functionality as `qlik-cli` but havent tested quite well
- another (not so sophisticated) method is to commit the script in a text file and commit an empty (binary) qvf file next to it. But since the qvf is a binadry you cant exactly track the changes made into it. Rely on commit messages

Comment: Is there a way to use qlik-cli with the Qlik Sense Enterprise version? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Its not heavily mentioned but i was able to connect (using JWT in my case): ` qlik context create QSEoW --server https://my-sense-instance/jwt --api-key eyJhbGciO...` and then use the unbuild command